# multiple definition in C++ including header

Tags: c++

I have a project with multiple file as below:

```
//header.h
class example {...}

//variable.h
#include "header.h"
example ex;

//main.cpp
#include "variable.h"
....

//src1.cpp
#include "variable.h"
```

when compiling the compiler error as: multiple definition of "ex"
I dont understand why, I want to use "ex" in main.cpp and src1.cpp, how should I do.
Thanks,

Comment: duplicate ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072244/c-multiple-definitions-of-a-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ multiple definitions of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072244/c-multiple-definitions-of-a-variable)

Comment: Just a clarification: you'd have exactly the same problem without "header.h" if "variable.h" had `int ex;` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By #including `variable.h` in both `main.cpp` and `src1.cpp`, you have defined variable `ex` twice.  The *linker* (not the compiler) won't like this.

Instead, change `variable.h` to look like this:

```
extern example ex;
```

And put:

```
example ex;
```

in (say) `src1.cpp`.

And yes, use include guards also, but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Use include guards in header.h and variable.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

class header {...}

#endif
```