# Why does extern need to be used when I have header guards?

Tags: c++

I was having some trouble with "multiple definitions" errors and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072279/12794262) that highlights the need to use the `extern` keyword.

Here is the example used to explain the solution.

**FileA.h**

```
#ifndef FILEA_H_
#define FILEA_H_
#include "FileB.h"
void hello();

#endif /* FILEA_H_ */
```

**FileB.cpp**

```
#include "FileB.h"

int wat = 0;

void world()
{
    //more code;
}
```

**FileB.h**

```
#ifndef FILEB_H_
#define FILEB_H_

extern int wat;  // The solution makes this change with the definition being in FileB.cpp
void world();


#endif /* FILEB_H_ */
```

Essentially, `extern` is needed to let the compiler know that `wat` is *defined* elsewhere in the code, and to avoid `wat` being declared multiple times when FileB.h is included multiple times.

MY QUESTION IS, how would `wat` be declared multiple times without the extern keyword? Specifically, the use of

```
#ifndef FILEB_H_
#define FILEB_H_
```

should be enough to avoid multiple definitions, as these header guards would prevent FileB.h from executing more than once. I tried it myself and the extern keyword IS needed to avoid errors. Does it have something to do with the linker? Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: Header guards do not protect against multiple sources defining the same variable causing a violation of the ODR.

Comment: The include guard is enough to prevent multiple definitions _per c++ source file_. The problem in your linked example comes from having two _different_ `c++` source files, `FileA.cpp` and `FileB.cpp`, that both indirectly include the declaration `int wat;` So today's lesson is: Never declare data in a `#include` file without the `extern` keyword.

Comment: Wow, I never realized that header guards only prevent multiple definitions within a single source file. Thanks for the helpful responses!